# Inheritance in class methods

Tags: objective-c

I have the following class:

```
@interface ClassA

+ (void)method1;
+ (void)method2;

@end

@implementation ClassA

+ (void)method2 {
     [self method1];
  }

@end
```

And one that inherits from it:

```
@interface ClassB : ClassA
@end

@implementation ClassB

+ (void)method1 {
   NSLog(@"ClassB");
}

@end
```

If in an specific segment of code I do:

```
[ClassB method2];
```

It will throw an error cause it will try to call [ClassA method1], but this class doesn't implement that method. Is it even possible somehow that call is make to ClassB and not to ClassA? Scenario is: I have a base class with some utility class methods that relate in between them. Children don't need to implement those, but need to implement one that is used inside some of those methods. But once the flow goes into the parent, when it calls this method, it calls the parent one - which is not implemented.

Comment: Please post example code that actually compiles. ClassA isn't valid because you haven't provided an implementation for `method1`. All of your methods declare a return type but don't return anything. You are missing a classname after `@implementation`.

Comment: Your code wouldn't actually compile but the concept you are trying to show does work without throwing any errors and would call `method1` on `ClassB`.  You should give `ClassA` an implementation for all the methods it declares in its interface though.

Comment: That's it Dan. I had a long hierarchy of different calls and in one of the methods I was calling the parent class instead of self. Which was then calling all class methods on the parent and not on the specific child. Working now.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple problems:

**First**
First point deleted thanks to @rmaddy comments.

**Second**

Your methods return a `instancetype` variable, while they don't: if you want to leave your implementation like that, change your method to return `void`

**Third**

You forgot implementation of `+ (instancetype)method1;` so this code it not valid.

Comment: Your first point is wrong. `self` is perfectly valid in a class method. It refers to the class itself. And it's perfectly valid to call another class method from a class method using `self`.